# Jvectormap syntax Error color country

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I want to implement jvectormap on a website. 
The vectormap works fine without any individual parameters.
Now I'd like to change the color for different countries, starting with germany and france.

My code is (you can ignore the marker part, it get's interesting at the end - regions...)

```
<body>
  <div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
  <script>
$(function(){
  $('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: '#383f47'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'},
      {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
      {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
      {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
      {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
      {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
      {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
      {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
      {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
      {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
      {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
      {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
      {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
      {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
      {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
      {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
      {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
      {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
      {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
      {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
      {latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati'},
      {latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga'},
      {latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica'},
      {latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius'},
      {latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain'},
      {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
    ]
      regions: [{
          scale: {            '1': '#4169E1',            '2': '#FF69B4'          },
          attribute: 'fill',
          values: {"DE":1,"FR":2},
        }]
}
  });
});
  </script>
```

I get a syntax error but I can't figure out where it is?

> missing } after property list

Answer (score 1):

This work :

```
$(function(){
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill',
        scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        hoverColor: false,
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: 'red',
                stroke: '#383f47'
            }
        },
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        markers: [
            {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'},
            {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
            {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
            {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
            {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
            {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
            {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
            {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
            {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
            {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
            {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
            {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
            {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
            {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
            {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
            {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
            {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
            {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
            {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
            {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
            {latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati'},
            {latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga'},
            {latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica'},
            {latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius'},
            {latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain'},
            {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
        ],
        regions: [{
            scale: {            '1': '#4169E1',            '2': '#FF69B4'          },
            attribute: 'fill',
            values: {"DE":1,"FR":2},
        }]
    });
});
```

You've missed a comma before `regions` and had a `}` extra

Comment: thanks a lot - syntax now works and the map is shown correctly. But unfortunately the country colors don't change?? =.=

Comment: Open a new subject with the code and an img to show what you've got and what you want

Comment: did so : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191725/jvectormap-change-country-color