# jvectormap change country color

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm using a jvectormap on a website which is working with markers, but I fail to change the color of a specific country. I took the documented examples and no errors are given.

My code is:

```
$(function(){
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill',
        scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        hoverColor: false,
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: 'red',
                stroke: '#383f47'
            }
        },
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        markers: [
            {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'},
            {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
            {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
            {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
            {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
            {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
            {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
            {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
            {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
            {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
            {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
            {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
            {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
            {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
            {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
            {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
            {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
            {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
            {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
            {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
            {latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati'},
            {latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga'},
            {latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica'},
            {latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius'},
            {latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain'},
            {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
        ],
        regions: [{
            scale: {            '1': 'yellow',            '2': 'red'          },
            attribute: 'fill',
            values: {"DE":1,"FR":2},
        }]
    });
});
```

The result is this:
https://picload.org/image/raldwolo/unbenannt.png

Answer (score 0):

It works now - my code:

```
$(function(){
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: '#383f47'
        }
    },
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    markers: [
        {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'},
        {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
        {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
        {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
        {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
        {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
        {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
        {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
        {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
        {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
        {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
        {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
        {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
        {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
        {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
        {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
        {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
        {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
        {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
        {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
        {latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati'},
        {latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga'},
        {latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica'},
        {latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius'},
        {latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain'},
        {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
    ],
    map: 'world_mill',
    container: $('#world-map'),
    series: {
    regions: [{
        scale: {            '1': 'yellow',            '2': 'red'          },
        attribute: 'fill',
        values: {"DE":1,"FR":2},
    }]
}
});
```

});